# Referencing REST API resource from CDK in amplify custom resource

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, aws-cdk

I need to customize the method handler for a REST API endpoint and point it to SQS instead of a Lambda function. I'm stalling out trying to get a full reference to the `RestApi` object...

The RestApi object I get back from `RestApi.fromRestApiId` is incomplete; I can't do this:

```
const restApi = apigateway.RestApi.fromRestApiId(this, 'RestApi', dependencies.api.rest.ApiId);
const queueResource = restApi.root.resourceForPath('/webhooks');
```

...without getting this error:
`Error: root is not configured when imported using fromRestApiId(). Use fromRestApiAttributes() API instead.`

I can't use `RestApi.fromRestApiAttributes` as that requires the `rootResourceId` -- which **I can't seem to find a reference to**. The documentation for `RestApi.fromRestApiAttributes` shows this, but I don't have `props`:

```
const api = RestApi.fromRestApiAttributes(this, 'RestApi', {
  restApiId: props.restApiId,
  rootResourceId: props.rootResourceId,
});
```

Does anyone know how to access the `rootResourceId`?

Answer (score 0):

The [root resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-settings-method-request.html#setup-method-resources) (`/`) id is a alphanumeric string like `4cfzeywftb`, which can be found in the console breadcrumbs:

```
APIs > API (076t2zozc0) > Resources> / (4cfzeywftb)
```

or by calling `get-resources`:

```
aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id 076t2zozc0
```

```json
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "4cfzeywftb",
            "path": "/",
            "resourceMethods": {
                "ANY": {}
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "36g7tq",
            "parentId": "4cfzeywftb",
            "pathPart": "{proxy+}",
            "path": "/{proxy+}",
            "resourceMethods": {
                "ANY": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Console won't work -- I'm trying to incorporate this into a IaC stack to spin these environments up for developers, etc. Is there not a way with CDK directly?

Comment: @Ryan where are you sourcing `props.restApiId` from?  That would be the short answer.  However, if you can't treat the resource ID as a static value, another idiomatic option would be to call `GetResources` with the JS SDK in your CDK application code to fetch the `rootResourceId` value [at synth-time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-context).

Comment: sorry, the `props.restApiId` is from the documentation. Using `AmplifyHelpers.addResourceDependency` to get api information includes the ApiId but NOT the `restResourceId`...

Comment: @Ryan Please add this new info to the OP.  Also, `console.log` the API ID you get from the helper.